# How can I allow access to a specific folder with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file and I am trying to allow access to a sub website (within a folder) under our existing site.

I'm using the following within my .htaccess file, but when I try to navigate to the folder that I want allowed I get a 403 error.

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .html

<Directory /teen-writers/>
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have also tried implementing this code:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

But when the above code is implemented, along with:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```

I have access to the sub site/folder, but then one of my .html pages is no longer rendered as a .php page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `Directory` directive inside htaccess. Try putting this in an htaccess file inside `teen-writers` folder.

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: Thanks. As it turns out, I already had an .htaccess file within that folder. Totally forgot.

Comment: That does not make sense to me, surely you must have to put some setting in place to indicate that a folder is accessible?

Comment: In my case I had to add a line stating `Satisfy any` and it worked